"Romantic" (likewise "Romanticism") historically always capitalised?
In contrast to e.g. "liberalism" and "modernism" — which have likewise referred to people with common intellectual identities — it is convention to capitalise "Romanticism". In the literary discourse of that time surrounding the movement, was it also commonly capitalised?
Maybe it was influenced by the German-language discourse, as nouns in German are capitalised?
Some more examples of varying capitalisation afforded to intellectual movements: (StackExchange) Capitalization of artistic trends.

Note that 'm/Modernism' has two [Cambridge Dictionary]  or more senses, and the srt (etc) movement sense is often capitalised [Britannica, University of Toledo, Conc Ox comp to Eng Lit,...] M-W adds another meaning with the caveat 'often capitalised'.

We capitalise proper nouns. So normally it's a Romantic poet (nearly always one who was part of the artistic and intellectual movement that originated in Europe towards the end of the 18th century). But a romantic person is just a person for whom adjectival romantic is a good descriptor.

Have you read what Wikipedia says? The term was popularised by Germaine de Staël, who was French, and wasn't generally used in English till the 1820s, well into the history of the movement (Blake's Songs 1794, Lyrical Ballads 1798, most of Goethe's works pre-1810, Keats died in 1821). So no point in researching whether it was capitalized in the 1790s.

Likewise 'romanticism' could mean 'a tendency to be romantic' as distinct from the name of the movement.

A lot of research in this question can be done in commonly-available sources like Wikipedia and online dictionaries, and the OP should have done this research, as well as being more precise about what period/texts they're interested in. The adjective romantic dates to the 1650s, meaning "of the nature of a literary romance, partaking of the heroic or marvelous", and in the early 19th century was used in contrast with "classical" for anything unclassical. Not capitalized in those senses.

Looking at ngram results, it is not obvious that "it is convention to capitalize Romanticism", many capitalizations being due  to the occurrence of the word in titles. Perhaps, someone may have an explanation on the evolution of the ngram curves with a tipping point in the seventies.

There is no absolute rule as regards capitalization. From the ngram for "Romantic poet,romantic poet", it can be seen that roughly over the whole of the 19th century, when the term can be considered to be relevant, no capitalization is used; capitalization starts in the 20th century, but even for most of this century the largely dominant form has no capital. It is only at the end of the 20th century that the rapidly climbing curve of the lower-case form overtakes the other. We have a similar graph for "the Romantic poets,the romantic poets", which is a term that  hardly refers to any  acceptation of "romantic" other than that connected with the artistic movement (the why of this latter assertion, being the intuitive notion that generalizations about romantic poets not typically considered as part of the movement must be rare).


A similar evoultion is shown for the Romantic movement,the romantic movement.

The spelling of "(R/r)omanticism" follows a similar evolution.

It is not a convention, today, to capitalize "(R/r)omanticism"; you do have a choice. Here is what the OALD (Oxford Advanced learner's Dictionary) has to say.

romanticisùm 1 (Also Romanticism) a style or movement in art, music and literature, in the late 18th and 19th century, i n which strong feelings, imagination and a return to nature were more important than reason, order, INTELLECTUAL ideas.

From the ngrams it can be concluded that historically the dominant practice was not the capitalization of the terms having to do with the movement and that the trend toward capitalization for those terms became dominant in the second half of the 20th century.
It can be inferred that the impetus at the root of capitalization is not German linguistic practices but simply a necessity to make clear that the  implied reference is  the artistic period ((R/r)omanticism).
The following article about the terms concerning Romanticism  concurs with the above conclusion on capitalization.

(Romantic Poetry and Related Terms: Romanticism, New Romanticism, Neo-Romanticism, Post-Romanticism, Late Romanticism) If there is an overused and misunderstood term in English poetry today, it is probably "romantic" in its various incarnations. […] While romantic poetry can, of course, be about romance, in its most general sense, romantic poetry can be about virtually anything and the term pertains more to the style, attitude and worldview of the poet than to any specific theme. The term Romantic is most often capitalized when the Romantic movement/school (and perhaps religion) is being discussed, although there is no absolute rule in regard to capitalization.

